# php, url hiding with the .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is the real url:

```
http://web/app/index.php?id=1
```

Here I have used current .htaccess and working fine with me.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?id=$1
```

Now the url is : `http://web.com/app/index/i` and working fine

but here is the problem the real url

http://web.com/app/index.php?id=1&name=abc

How can I set mention url with .htaccess for keep it short or any other good solution for hiding URL-.
is it possible to show user only one url like , http://web.com/app but it could go to other pages while the url stay one url static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we say, good practice is to rewrite everything to one `index` page, like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

then in your `index.php` you get uri by `$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` :

```
http://example.com/app -> $uri = /app
http://example.com/app/sub-app -> $uri = /app/sub-app
```

but also query string applies to the `$uri` variable:

```
http://example.com/app/?a=1&b=3 -> $uri = /app/?a=1&b=3
```

in this case, if you want to examine just uri part before `?` question mark:

```
$realRri = strtok($uri,'?'); // and you have '/app/' instead of '/app/?a=1&b=3'
```

next you can examine and manipulate `$uri`;

**Example**:

```
$trimmedUri = trim($realRri, '/');

if ($trimmedUri == 'app')
{
    // you can show app page
}
elseif ($trimmedUri == 'contact') 
{
    // show contact
}
else 
{
    // show 404 page not found
}


// you can have some dynamic also also

if (is_file($filePath = 'custom-page/'.$trimmedUri))
{
    include $filePath;
}
else 
{
    // 404 page
}
```

**Final Code (regarding your current script)**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

#rewrite php file
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ $1.php 
#rwwrite with id
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 
#rewrite with id and name
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2&name=$3
```

Comment: this is good answer but here i have almost finished my project, so just wana change the link of / http://loc/app/index.php?id=1&name=abc  to http://loc/app/index/1/abc

Comment: you can use this rule: `RewriteRule ^index/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&name=$2`, but consider the rule order, you may use that as first rule in this case

Comment: let me know, where do you put your `.htaccess` file? with this: `http://web.com/app/index/i` is it in `http://web.com/` or in `http://web.com/app/` it's gonna be important

Comment: it's inside the folder which the php file is located.

Comment: yes but, is it inside the web root directory? i mean if `/app` part is also rewritten or `/app` is the directory?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is something like AJAX, mostly because of

> but it could go to other pages while the url stay one url static.

in which case, you would looking at JavaScript and not php. You would need a way to quickly deal with the data and change it how you want it. I've recently started learning Angular, and it shows a lot of promise. Go through the tutorial yourself (just google angular.js and the tutorial is on their website), or some other JavaScript library (unless you want to hard-code everything, in which case, good luck) like jQuery or MooTools (names mentioned because they're libraries i have knowledge with). To my knowledge (I am no code guru) but a website's URI is what tells the server what to show you. You can make shortcuts

If, however, you want for it to just not have the .php filename, then I believe that

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php\??(.*)$ $1.php&$2
```

Should, theoretically get you what you want.

Note: I can't test it right now, so it may error out.

EDIT: It does error out.